# How to get coordinates of X,Y,Z from a 3D object?

Tags: 3d, coordinates, fbx

I wanted to add annotations to my 3D objects. Right now I'm using sketchfab to store and to do the annotations. However I want to save the markers' coordinates into my db. Is that possible and how can I extract the coordinates?

Comment: I think more details are needed here. What are the datatypes you have access to from the `.fbx` file and what is your db look like?

Comment: My db just have four columns, id, X, Y, Z, each to store the coordinates accordingly. Not quite sure what you mean by the data types, but all I did was upload it in sketchfab.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.